# Get id of latest inserted row in JDBC with preparedstatemtnt

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, jdbc

I have followed DAO pattern for my project and made separate file for handeling DB connection. I have found answer in other posts/questions but they had used Statemtnt and I have used PreparedStatemtnt. How do I get the id of latest inserted row using PreparedStatement.

```
private DBConn conn = new DBConn();
private String sql = "";

@Override
public boolean insert(Post t) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    conn.openConnection();
    sql = "insert into posts (title,slug,category_id,content) values (?,?,?,?)";

    PreparedStatement stmt = conn.inti(sql);
    stmt.setString(1, t.getTitle());
    stmt.setString(2, t.getSlug());
    stmt.setInt(3, t.getCategoryID());
    stmt.setString(4, t.getContent());

    int result = conn.executeUpdate();
    if (result > 0) {
        return true;
    }
    conn.closeConnection();
    return false;
}
```

I tried it by :

```
int result = conn.executeUpdate( Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
```

I gets marked as error stating :

```
method executeUpdate in class DBConn cannot be applied to given types
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have found answer in other posts/questions but they had used
>   Statement and I have used PreparedStatemtnt.

The `PreparedStatement` interface extends the `Statement` interface.

```
public interface PreparedStatement extends Statement {...
```

So you can use the `public ResultSet getGeneratedKeys()`method defined in the 
`Statement` interface to retrieve generated id(s).

> How do I get the id of latest inserted row using PreparedStatement.

With your actual code you will not retrieve the latest inserted row but the generated id of the actual inserted row.
If the application is multi-threaded, a row could be inserted between the `executeUpdate()` return and the time where you retrieve the generated id.

You should also create the `PreparedStatement` instance by using the 
`PreparedStatement prepareStatement(String sql, String columnNames[])` method to be able to retrieve the generated id.

According to the Javadoc of that method:

> Creates a default PreparedStatement object capable of returning the
>   auto-generated keys designated by the given array. This array contains
>   the names of the columns in the target table that contain the
>   auto-generated keys that should be returned. The driver will ignore
>   the array if the SQL statement is not an INSERT statement, or an SQL
>   statement able to return auto-generated keys (the list of such
>   statements is vendor-specific).

You could do something like that :

```
String[] generatedId = { "ID" };
String  sql = "insert into posts (title,slug,category_id,content) values (?,?,?,?)";

PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql, generatedId);
 . . . 
int result = statement.executeUpdate();
if (result > 0) {
   ...
   try { ResultSet rs = statement.getGeneratedKeys();
      if (rs.next()) {
         long id = rs.getLong(1);
       }

    }

   ...
}
```

Comment: As per your suggestion I changed my code in ` PreparedStatement stmt = conn.inti(sql,generatedId);` and I'm getting error `Method init in class DBConn. Required:String, 
Found:String[ ]`. My `init` method in DBConn looks like this::
 `public PreparedStatement inti(String sql) throws SQLException {
        stmt = conn.prepareCall(sql);
        return stmt;
    }`
when changed to: 
`public PreparedStatement inti(String sql,String[] id) throws SQLException {
        stmt = conn.prepareCall(sql,id);
        return stmt;
    }`
and got all  DAOImpl classes marked red.